# Is it possible to get who is the email service provider of the particular mail using JavaMail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail jar to read the mail from my Gmail inbox. 
I am able to read the content of the mail. But I want to know who is the email service provider of the mail.

Actually, we can find those details in 'Show Original' of the Gmail. I want to get that using JavaMail API. Is there any way for getting the mail provider?

Please help me.

[image: Please see the screenshot]

Comment: "Show original" shows you the MIME content of the message.  You can access all of that using JavaMail.  What part of the MIME content of the message do you believe shows who the email service provider is?

Comment: @BillShannon - It is not part bodypart. This information lies behind the mail content. You can see Received: ***-***-*** esp if you open the show original

Comment: The Received message headers are accessible from JavaMail with the [getHeader method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-).  But not that they're not 100% reliable, and they don't always follow any sort of strict syntax so be careful how much you depend on them.

Comment: @BillShannon - Yes. It worked. Please write answer I will accept as correct as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Received message headers are accessible from JavaMail with the [getHeader method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getHeader-java.lang.String-). But note that they're not 100% reliable, and they don't always follow any sort of strict syntax so be careful how much you depend on them.